# How to convert date time to double c#

Tags: c#, json, datetime, type-conversion, double

I'm trying to convert a date and time value from a JSON string to a double in C#, but I keep getting the below error.
[image]

Below is the code i am trying to debug.

```
 DateTime baseDate = DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime.Parse("1970-01-01"), DateTimeKind.Utc);
 docRoot.scheduleDate = baseDate.AddSeconds((double)docRoot.scheduleDate);
```

I understand what the error is saying but I've been having a difficult time finding a workaround. I've tried the approach below but havent succeeded.

1. Converting `docRoot.scheduleDate`to a string, then trying to convert the string to a double using `Convert.ToDouble(stringScheduleDate)`. The only issue here is that the special characters in the `docRoot.scheduleDate` ("10/10/2019 08:29:30") are causing a format error.

I believe that if i remove the special characters i'll resolve the issue.  But i'm wondering if there is a different approach to getting past this exception?

Converting to a string then removing the special characters seems a bit inefficient in my opinion, so if anyone is willing to contribute some other ideas I much appreciate it.

Comment: Hi.  Would love to help, but it's unclear what you're asking.  Where is there JSON parsing? I don't see any going on in the code you've shared. What does an example value look like in the JSON itself?  Is it simply that your JSON contains a Unix timestamp?  If so, how did you get `scheduleDate` into a `DateTime` to begin with?  Please consider revising your question to be [a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the Ticks to double very easily:

```
docRoot.scheduleDate = baseDate.AddSeconds((double)docRoot.scheduleDate.Second);
```

I just realized this was for an add seconds method, this will work better

Also of note. The OADate internally uses a private InternalTicks property too. So that could also cause issues.

Comment: I tried the above and "Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue' does not contain a definition for 'Ticks" exception. Which is confusing because i thought docRoot.scheduleDate was being recognized as a DateTime object because of its format.

Comment: @hfires yes, that's on docRoot after parsed to a datetime?

Comment: I am parsing like this: DateTime newScheduleDate = Convert.ToDateTime(docRoot.scheduleDate) , then trying docRoot.scheduleDate = baseDate.AddSeconds((double)newScheduleDate.Seconds); but i am getting a syntax error

Comment: I figured it out. It should be newScheduleDate.Second (not Seconds). THANKS FOR THE HELP!

Comment: @hfires - I don't see how this could be.  `DateTime` has a `Second` property, ranging from `0` to `59`.  `TimeSpan` has a `Seconds` property, but its range is `-59` to `59`.  I would guess that you probably care about values larger than that range.  It would help if you clarified your question (see my comment above).  Thanks.

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint ugh. You are right! I got all caught up in the other thread that was here and goofed...

Answer (score 0):

Use `DateTime.ToOADate` to get a decimal representation as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tooadate and `DateTime.FromOADate` to deserialize.